# Bootstrap Column Sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, size

I need to use 1170px for content however i'm worried about column sizes and gutter widths. I Have three big columns with 300px and one small 150px column. Gutter width is 40px. I'm creating this on PSD and wanted to learn if it is okay for Bootstrap.

Comment: Welcome. If you provide more details about what you mean by "okay for Bootstrap" you will receive better answers, and the question may be more useful for other users in the future.

Comment: hello, i mean if column sizes and gutter width are suitable for Bootstrap Standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the defaults for Bootstrap won't work with your site out of the box, you can customize virtually every aspect of it and download that customized copy to include in your project.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Either way, you can include Bootstrap via the CDN links provided on the Getting Started page, so you can include them without adding a bunch of files to your project to quickly test whether or not the defaults will work.